# Конструктор ошибок javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, как более правильно создавать ошибки в Javascript из прототипа так, чтобы с ними удобнее было работать. Например, если я создаю ошибку таким образом, то выбрасывая исключение, нужно вызывать `constructor`, опять же, проверяя на принадлежность ошибки к моему классу, снова приходится дергать `constructor`.

```
var SpecificError = Object.create(Error.prototype);
    SpecificError.constructor = function(message) {
      this.name = 'Specific Error';
      this.message = message;
      this.stack = (new Error).stack;
      return this;
    };
    SpecificError.constructor.prototype = SpecificError;
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ifeature/bpc0f147/1/)

Comment: что-то тут все в кучу смешалось. в данном случае если вы переименуете поле _constructor_ в любой другое - ничего не изменится. Какой результат был ожидаем для этого кода?

Comment: В данном случае, я хочу отлавливать только, так сказать "определенные" ошибки, не все. Например, в try/catch/finally я проверяю, скажем так: `if(e instanceof SpecificError.constructor)`, если это именно эта ошибка, то обрабатываю, если другая - просто выбрасываю снова.

Comment: и как хотелось использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему здесь хотелось использовать наследование.
Для этого нужно было сделать `SpecificError` функцией конструктором

```
function SpecificError(message){
    ...
}
```

Внутри его вызвать конструктор базового класса, в данном случае `Error`

```
Error.call(this,message);
```

а далее установить прототип

```
SpecificError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

**Но,** наследоваться от `Error` не так просто, так как его конструктор не оперирует с `this` и следовательно не добавит в него автоматом нужные свойства.
Но, можно использовать решение из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17936621/2881286), сохранить полученный экземпляр Error, назначить ему `name` и использовать его `stack`

```
function SpecificError(message, name) {
  var err = Error.call(this, message);
  err.name = this.name = (name || 'SpecificError');
  err.message = this.message = message;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
    get: function() {
      return err.stack;
    }
  });
}
```

Измененный пример из JSFiddle

```js
function SpecificError(message, name) {
  var err = Error.call(this, message);
  err.name = this.name = (name || 'SpecificError');
  err.message = this.message = message;
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
    get: function() {
      return err.stack;
    }
  });
}

SpecificError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);

function OtherError(message) {
  SpecificError.call(this, message, 'OtherError');
}
OtherError.prototype = Object.create(SpecificError.prototype);


try {
  throw new OtherError('Very specific error');
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof OtherError) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.stack);
  } else
    throw e;
}
```