# Скрытое свойство [[ErrorData]]

Tags: javascript

```js
function PropertyError(property) {
  this.name = "PropertyError";

  this.property = property;
  this.message = "Ошибка в свойстве " + property;

  if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, PropertyError);
  } else {
    this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
  }

}

PropertyError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

> **Конструктор родителя здесь не обязателен**
>
> Обычно, когда мы наследуем, то вызываем конструктор родителя. В данном случае вызов выглядит как Error.call(this, message).
>
> Строго говоря, этот вызов здесь не обязателен. Встроенный конструктор
>   Error ничего полезного не делает, даже свойство this.message (не
>   говоря уже о name и stack) не назначает. Единственный возможный смысл
>   его вызова – он ставит специальное внутреннее свойство [[ErrorData]],
>   которое выводится в toString и позволяет увидеть, что это ошибка.
>   Поэтому по стандарту вызывать конструктор Error при наследовании в
>   таких случаях рекомендовано.

Источник: [Learn Javascript - Свои ошибки, наследование от Error](https://learn.javascript.ru/oop-errors).

Подскажите пожалуйста что за свойство `[[ErrorData]]`?

Я просто попробовал проверить это свойство в контексте этого примера и мне выдало:

```
function PropertyError(property) {
  Error.call(this, property) ;
  this.name = "PropertyError";

  this.property = property;
  this.message = "Ошибка в свойстве " + property;

  if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
    Error.captureStackTrace(this);
  } else {
    this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
  }

}

var a = new PropertyError('Hey');
var aa = Error('Hey');

console.log(String(a));
console.log(String(aa));
VM1377:19 [object Object]
VM1377:20 Error: Hey
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Конструктор ошибок javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490010/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%ba-javascript)

Comment: @Grundy я совсем о другом спрашивал.

Comment: Если ты считаешь, что твой вопрос отличается - ты можешь отредактировать его.

Comment: @Grundy как я его отредактирую, если все примеры будут одинаковым и содержание не поменять?

Comment: что значит _примеры будут одинаковыми и содержание не поменять_? Удали все лишнее из вопроса. Оставь только, что действительно относится к вопросу

Comment: @Grundy как мне изменить вопрос, что бы он не был дубликатом ибо все что я привел как довод не поменять? изменить имя конструктора, или мне самому написать, которое я привел в приме с сайта в котором говориться об этом свойстве. В дубликате ни слово не сказана о скрытом свойстве `[[ErrorData]]`.

Comment: Если ты хочешь спросить, что за свойство [[ErrorData]]? так и надо спрашивать. Пока же у тебя вопрос: как унаследоваться от Error. Непонятно что должны показывать сниппет и блок кода в вопросе и как они относятся к вопросу?

Comment: @Grundy ничего такого у меня нет. я четко спросил: Подскажите пожалуйста что за свойство [[ErrorData]]?

Comment: Внутренние маркеры - это указатели спецификации, а не реализации. Если объект помечен как ошибка, то другие могут об этом узнать, [пример](http://xahlee.info/javascript_es6/js_es6_s19.html#sec-object.prototype.tostring). Туда же `[[prototype]]` спёки (не `prototype`, а `__proto__` в реализации).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указано в [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-properties-of-error-instances):

> The only specified uses of [[ErrorData]] is to identify `Error` and `NativeError` instances as Error objects within `Object.prototype.toString`.

---

> `[[ErrorData]]` используется *только* для определения того, что объекты классов `Error` и `NativeError` являются объектами ошибки при передаче их в `Object.prototype.toString`

Если пройти в `Object.prototype.toString`, то можно увидеть следующую проверку

> Else if `O` has an [[ErrorData]] internal slot, let builtinTag be "Error".

---

> Если у `O` есть внутренний слот `[[ErrorData]]`, установить значение для `builtinTag` в `Error`.

В конечном итоге это нужно для вывода строки вида: "[object ", tag,  "]"

В случае `Error` она будет выглядеть так: `[object Error]`

---

Вместо вызова конструктора, переопределить это поведение можно установив объекту свойство с именем `Symbol.toStringTag`

```js
var t = {
  [Symbol.toStringTag]: "Error"
};

var t2 = {};
var t3 = new Error("err");

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(t));
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(t2));
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(t3));
```

Comment: спасибо за проделанную работу. Я приводил пример где использовал внутри конструктора `Error.call(this, property);`, но это ничего не дало. все так же выводиться: `[object Object]`. Цитирую: `Единственный возможный смысл его вызова – он ставит специальное внутреннее свойство [[ErrorData]], которое выводится в toString и позволяет увидеть, что это ошибка.`

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, потому что неверно используешь. Посмотри ответ, который был в дубликате: конструктор `Error` **ничего** не делает с объектом `this`, поэтому вызов `Error.call(this, property)` **ничего** не делает. Чтобы это заработало, используй классы и синтаксис с `super`

Comment: добавь линк на свой ответ - дубликат. Тогда зачем они об этом пишут что это работает? Я помню про `this`, ибо читал твой ответ, но на тот момент меня просто это не интересовало.

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, _Тогда зачем они об этом пишут что это работает?_ - потому что они ошиблись :)

Comment: @ВиталикЧерный, ссылка в первом комментарии под вопросом и справа в "Связанных вопросах"

Comment: мы можешь пойти в какой нибудь чат, ибо у меня есть еще пару вопросов, только если ты не против)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69050/discussion-between-grundy-and--).